# Undefined index: submit

Tags: php, forms, indexing, submit, undefined

I have made this simple php to check if a number is a positive or a negative. It works but I get this notice: Undefined index: submit.

```
<?php
if (!$_POST["submit"])
    {
    ?>
    <body>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            Enter a number: <input name="number" size="2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
    </body>
    <?php
}
else
{
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    if ($number > 0)
    {
        echo 'You entered a positive number';
    }
    elseif ($number < 0)
    {
        echo 'You entered a negative number';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You entered 0';
    }
}
?>
```

Im new at php so if you can and want :)

Comment: When the page first loads there will be no values in `$_POST` values. $_POST will only be populated when your form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the second line with:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$_POST["submit"]` appears to be empty. It will be inverted thanks to the ! and output true, so your program works.

But you never Post any value with the name submit, its the name of the button. I think you want to check if `$_POST["number"]` is empty.

```
if (!empty($_POST["number"])) {
    //your stuff here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition

```
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (!$_POST["submit"])
```

with

```
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second line:

```
if (!$_POST['submit'])
```

with:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Comment: This is more or less just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21599105).